# Angularjs - TypeError: Object #<Scope> has no method 'path'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make a simple redirect when pressing a button on the my page, but for some reason I keep getting the following error.

```
TypeError: Object #<Scope> has no method 'path'
```

Not sure what causes it to happen. My code is as following:

*controller.js*

```
mycontroller.controller('OrderCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope','$location',function($scope, $http, $location, $rootScope) {
...
$scope.confirmOrder = function confirmOrder() {
    $location.path("/order");
}; 
...
}]);
```

*page.jade*

```
input.green-button(type="submit",value="Confirm order",ng-controller="OrderCtrl", ng-click="confirmOrder()")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are injecting `$rootScope` as variable `$location` and vica-versa. Just correct the injection correctly.

Use

```
mycontroller.controller('OrderCtrl', 
                        ['$scope', 
                         '$http', 
                         '$rootScope', 
                         '$location', function($scope, 
                                               $http, 
                                               $rootScope, 
                                               $location) {
}]);
```

instead of

```
mycontroller.controller('OrderCtrl', 
                        ['$scope', 
                         '$http', 
                         '$rootScope', //Notice here
                         '$location', function($scope, 
                                               $http, 
                                               $location, //Notice here
                                               $rootScope) {
}]);
```

Comment: Wow, completely, missed that. Thanks!

Comment: Before we figured out that our build process dealt with the quoted injector elements, we used the following layout: put each array on a separate line, and line up each element with its quoted doppleganger.  That way you will always see if you've included everything, and included it in the right order.